# How to get event when click destroy button before document was closed

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a problem for my MFC project as follows:

When I click on the destroy button, I want to show a messagebox "asking save file" before document closed.

But I can't.

The message is always shown after the document was closed.

A lot of places that I have placed code.

- `CloseDocument` Function of  Document Class
- `OnDestroy` Function of MainFrame Class
- `Destructor` Function of View Class
- `ExitInstance` Function of App Class

But without success.

Can someone show what's wrong?

Comment: If I remember correctly (last done MFC about 15 years ago) you will have to handle WM_CLOSE, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close... ah yes here it is : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/closing-the-window

Comment: If your app is Document/View-based, you can just call `GetDocument()->SetModifiedFlag();` in every point in your code that modifies the document contents. The framework will ask the user whether to save the unsaved documents.

Answer (score 1):

A [`WM_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) message is sent to a window when the user wants close it. A custom message handler can decide whether it wants to initiate window destruction from here, or go back (or initiate window destruction after storing information).

In an MFC application this is reflected as the [`OnClose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onclose) member function of `CWnd` or a `CWnd`-derived classes (such as `CFrameWnd`). Client code can provide a custom implementation and wire it up through the message map. When it does it should only call into the base class implementation if it wants the program to terminate.

Assuming that your `CMainFrame` class derives from `CFrameWnd` you will need to make the following changes:

*MainFrm.h* (add the following class member)

```cpp
class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
    // ...

protected:
    void OnClose();

    // ...
};
```

*MainFrm.cpp* (message map)

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
    // ...
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

*MainFrm.cpp* (implementation)

```cpp
void CMainFrame::OnClose()
{
    if (::AfxMessageBox(_T("Close application?"), MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
    {
        // Have the base class initiate destruction
        CFrameWnd::OnClose();
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

An attempt to close the application's main window pops up a confirmation dialog. If the user selects *"Yes"*, the program terminates. Otherwise the program continues to execute. In that case the document will remain unchanged.

Comment: Sorry, that is overcomplicated! We need only an Oneliner. Just tell the document, that it is "dirty" ('SetModifiedFlag()') and the MFC framework will remember you with a dialog to save before the document is closing.

Comment: @tom That may be the solution to the problem, but this here is the answer to the question. If you insist that the question is wrong, you should comment on the question.

Comment: he asked ´When I click on the destroy button, I want to show a messagebox "asking save file" before document closed. That is exactly what 'SetModifiedFlag()'  does.

Comment: @tom There is no mention that the OP is indeed using the Doc/View infrastructure. The MFC [`CDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdocument-class) class doesn't have a `CloseDocument()` member, so it's reasonable to assume that they are using a custom implementation. Regardless of that, the question is asking for a way to intercept the event of a user closing the application. This answer addresses this, and works for any MFC program.

Comment: Thank you so much. your solution was applied in my project. it work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler approach, a Oneliner as described in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdocument-class?view=msvc-170#setmodifiedflag)

'By calling this function consistently, you ensure that the framework prompts the user to save changes before closing a document. Typically you should use the default value of TRUE for the bModified parameter. To mark a document as clean (unmodified), call this function with a value of FALSE.'

```
BOOL CMyDocument::OnNewDocument()
{
    if (!CDocument::OnNewDocument())
        return FALSE;

    // TODO: add reinitialization code here
    // (SDI documents will reuse this document)

    SetModifiedFlag(TRUE);    // Set this somewhere, when you want to safe the document before the document goes off

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will to try your solution.